# How can I open with App Command Bar on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

When running apps made for Windows 8/RT on Windows 10 they include support for the App Command UI triggered by a touch gesture; which seems to be no longer a thing in windows 10.

[image: App Commands]

So there are parts of the app that are hidden unless you use the gesture to open them, but since Windows 10 does not have this gesture, is there another way to open them besides clicking the burger icon and clicking "App Commands"just to see them?

A keyboard shortcut maybe? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I discovered the touch gestures still work; but not when the apps are in Windowed Mode. If you make the apps fullscreen; then the gestures work.

That is dragging from the top or the bottom of the screen.

Right clicking the screen also triggers the App Commands.